# What words typically collocate with "quite"?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

The word *quite* is often confusing to non-native speakers. Can you give me a list of words that typically collocate with *quite* when the meaning is 'extreme'?

Comment: I think it's possible everybody has misunderstood your question. While *"quite"* can mean *"very",*  *"not quite"* does not mean *"not very".* If I say a theater is *"not quite full",* it means *"nearly completely full".* If I say a theater is *"not very full",* it probably means *"fairly empty".*

Comment: In what dictionary does quite denote anything extreme?

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, this is the confusing thing about the question. Both [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quite) and [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1282538#m_en_us1282538) list several meanings, one of which is “completely”. That’s not the same as “extreme”, but I think it’s what annie must have meant.

Answer (score 3):

I think that rather on the association with certain words, it depends on the context and use.

*Quite* has 2 meanings:

1. to a certain degree;
2. absolutely, completely.

See [here](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/quite) for its usage, there is a note at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Any of them? The word *quite* in this context is an adverb with the same grammar and roughly the same meaning as *very*. You can pair it with any adjective that you'd like:

- quite handsome
- quite yellow
- quite expensive
- quite heavy
- etc.

Using *quite* in this way is somewhat formal, so in ordinary conversation you'd most often use *very*. (**Edit**: It's not really very archaic, so I removed that note.)

Comment: +1 Good answer. I would disagree about its being archaic; it's still used quite often in American English, and I'd say that it isn't quite as strong an intensifier as *very.* So unless you're being ironic, something that is *quite heavy* is heavier than something that is *somewhat heavy* but not as heavy as something that is *very heavy*.

Comment: I must say, to agree with @Peter, that it certainly can't be considered archaic here in the UK. It is, in fact, 'quite common' and I would classify its use as _frequent_ over _occasional_. It certainly isn't antiquated. I could probably make note of at least five occurrences per day in our office.

Comment: @Peter, @Mr., I bowed to popular demand and removed the statement that it was archaic.

Comment: @Peter, I agree(unless I'm archaic) I use it all the time. @JSBangs, To me there's also a subtle sense that the particular quality was previously unknown or known to a lesser extent. Quite heavy, might also imply that there was a question about it's weight previously.

Comment: In UK usage, it’s not really a synonym of “very”.  Like “rather”, it can act both as an intensifier and as the opposite. This has been discussed in at least a couple of other questions, eg [Ambiguity of “quite”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3452/ambiguity-of-quite)

Comment: -1 because you concentrate exclusively on one of the two very different meanings of "quite". It is these two meanings that make the word difficult for non-native speakers, and I believe what the original question was about.

Comment: @Colin, fair point. If the OP would give some more context I'd be able to answer better.

Comment: That would be quite OK ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because I am American, but to me, the only time *quite* means anything like *extreme* is when it is negated. Then it means *exactly, entirely, completely*; so that *not quite* means *not exactly*, *not entirely*. This is very common, and you don’t have to memorize words that collocate with it because negated *quite* can modify just about anything:

> *I wasn’t quite ready to do it.*
>
> *That’s not quite what I intended.*
>
> *We tried to find other projects to do and never quite managed to pull anything together.*

Otherwise, to me, it means *markedly, to an unusual degree*: *He’s quite tall*. But *quite tall* isn’t necessarily as tall as *extremely tall*.

*Quite* can mean *exactly, entirely, completely* even without negation, but then it strikes me as a bit British:

> *Quite right. / Quite so.* (British stock phrases meaning *yes, exactly*)
>
> *I'd quite forgotten I had it.* (British)
>
> *He knows how busy you are, of course, and quite understood.* (oh so very British)

In American English, when *quite* modifies a verb, it is almost always negated.

Setting aside the negated uses, in American English *quite* appears most often in: *quite different*, *quite frankly/honestly/simply*, *quite sure*, *quite well/good*, *quite possible/possibly/likely/often*, *quite surprised*, and *you’re quite welcome*.

Comment: In most of the phrases listed at the end, *quite* just means *markedly/especially*, not *extremely* or *exactly/entirely/completely*. The exception is *quite sure*, which means *completely sure*. That is the one positive use of *quite* to mean *completely* that doesn’t strike me as at all British.