# Confused with the real meaning of "QUITE"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I've been using the word 'quite' for a long time now. And I just learned its other meaning.
Based on Google/Dictionary:

1. to the utmost or most absolute extent or degree; absolutely; completely.
   "it's quite out of the question"
2. to a certain or fairly significant extent or degree; fairly.
   "it's quite warm outside"

---

I guess the question is: how would you know which of these two different meanings is used in a sentence (both in written or verbal)?

For instance, I was asked how's the exam. I would like to answer "It was a bit hard".
Now if I use the word `quite`: `The exam was quite hard!`, how would the other person know if I mean:

a. "it is absolutely hard!" or

b. "it is not so hard"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ambiguity of "quite"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3452/ambiguity-of-quite) In 'BrE', (especially of course with gradable adjectives!) 'quite' rarely means 'totally'. Care has to be taken with quite clear, quite sure ... where the 'fairly' reading (and substitution) works.

Comment: How can 'quite' be interpreted to mean "not very"? Do you have an example use in this sense? I mean, I would take "to a certain or fairly significant degree" to mean not just a little bit: I would take _It's quite warm_ to mean that it is definitely _very warm_.

Comment: @Conrado: for "quite warm", yes, I think it almost always means very warm. But "quite interesting", spoken in a British accent in a certain tone of voice, can mean "not all that interesting."

Comment: @PeterShor True; and I think that it works in an American accent too, but that's sarcastic, and would work with "very interesting" almost as well.